# Referring to a group or community of people of older age

Tags: politeness

I am not a native English speaker and need to ask for advice.

In formal English, is it polite or OK to refer to a group of those who are older as "old people"? If not, what would you suggest instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[The elderly](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/elderly)*** has a more neutral connotation:

> - Usage Note: ***Elderly applies to the stage of life well past middle age. When used as a noun in referring to older persons in general, it is relatively neutral, denoting a group of people whose common characteristic is advanced age:***  policy issues of special interest to the elderly.

(AHD)

Usage examples:

From [Attitudes Towards Funding of Long-term Care of the Elderly](https://books.google.it/books?id=No_ScefgJ1IC&pg=PA7&dq=%22the%20elderly%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYoKa5xdTOAhXD7BQKHWxvAjo4ChDoAQhQMAk#v=onepage&q=%22the%20elderly%22&f=false):

> - the previous chapter we noted that the principal issues concerning funding options ***for long-term care of the elderly is the mix of family and State contributions.*** To contextualise public attitudes to this and related issues, as subsequently ...

From [Rights of the Elderly](https://books.google.it/books?id=rVK0ncTeFQEC&pg=PA139&dq=%22the%20elderly%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxo_T7xdTOAhWLNxQKHQDnAW84FBDoAQhKMAc#v=onepage&q=%22the%20elderly%22&f=false):

> - ***Although less directly focused on the elderly,*** the Employee Benefits Security Administration of the Department of Labor and the Pension Benefit Guaranty Corporation.....

Answer (score 0):

Years are supposed to make you more experienced, so **wiser**, which translates into **senior**:

> [a person who is older than another person (Merriam-Webster)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/senior)